# layout_gravity doesn't work on button with weight setted

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I've a layout like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/posta_ateneo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|right" // DOESN'T WORK
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Button 1"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/unisound"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My result is something like:

[image: now]

But I want something like:

[image: what I want]

I know I can use `RelativeLayout` to positioning `button1` on the right but I can't use weight with that layout and I need it to support all screen size.

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"` try this

Comment: set gravity of the linearlayout4 as right|center_vertical

Comment: you should use `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_gravity` when aligning inside the bounds of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xml and tell if it be of some help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/posta_ateneo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Button 1"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


   <Button
        android:id="@+id/unisound"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: accept it as answer of the question, so it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following is your xml file which you want..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/posta_ateneo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            DOESN=""
            T=""
            WORK=""
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/unisound"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```